# How to remove a class function from a plugin by using remove_action()?

Tags: plugins, functions, hooks, actions

Result of the var_dump('parse_query'):

```
 WP_Hook::__set_state(array(
    'callbacks' => 
    array (
    10 => 
      array (
       '0000000003c8dc5e000000004a442b5dsort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order' => 
      array (
         'function' => 
       array (
      0 => 
      WM_Nova_Restaurant::__set_state(array(
         'version' => '0.1',
         'default_menu_item_loop_markup' => 
        array (
          'menu_tag' => 'section',
          'menu_class' => 'menu-items',
          'menu_header_tag' => 'header',
          'menu_header_class' => 'menu-group-header',
          'menu_title_tag' => 'h1',
          'menu_title_class' => 'menu-group-title',
          'menu_description_tag' => 'div',
          'menu_description_class' => 'menu-group-description',
        ),
         'menu_item_loop_markup' => 
        array (
          'menu_tag' => 'section',
          'menu_class' => 'menu-items',
          'menu_header_tag' => 'header',
          'menu_header_class' => 'menu-group-header',
          'menu_title_tag' => 'h2',
          'menu_title_class' => 'menu-group-title',
          'menu_description_tag' => 'div',
          'menu_description_class' => 'menu-group-description',
        ),
         'menu_item_loop_last_term_id' => false,
         'menu_item_loop_current_term' => false,
      )),
      1 => 'sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order',
    ),
    'accepted_args' => 1,
  ),
),
),
 'iterations' => 
  array (
   ),
  'current_priority' => 
 array (
  ),
   'nesting_level' => 0,
   'doing_action' => false,
  ))
```

I have tried these, but none of it worked:

```
 function RBTM_my_func(){
  global $WM_Nova_Restaurant;
  remove_action('parse_query','WM_Nova_Restaurant', 10); 
  remove_action('parse_query', 'WM_Nova_Restaurant>sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order', 10); 
  remove_action('parse_query',array("WM_Nova_Restaurant", "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 10); 
  remove_action('parse_query', array("WM_Nova_Restaurant", "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 1);
  remove_action('parse_query',array($WM_Nova_Restaurant, "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 10);
  do_hard_unregister_object_callback( 'parse_query', 10, 'RBTM_my_func');
 }
  add_action('parse_tax_query', 'RBTM_my_func', 10);
```

So how do I remove this particular class function?  `WM_Nova_Restaurant->sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` 
[link](https://www.screencast.com/t/fL74gGbpqu)

I tried seeking for answers but couldn't find anything. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!!

Comment: It depends how they were originally hooked. Is `sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` hooked as a static method? Is there  a global variable for an instance of `WM_Nova_Restaurant`? Is `WM_Nova_Restaurant` a singleton? It's not possible to answer this question without knowing answers to those questions. If you don't know how to find out you need to contact the plugin author.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/PxF3iOcUk - isn't this enough? or are there any plugins to know the info of that function inside the hook & how to possibly remove it? or just `var_dump()` like what i did with the hook `parse_query`

Comment: @RayMacz can you find the code that does the `add_action` call? It's incredibly difficult if not near impossible to tell just from that Query Monitor output. Looking for that class in the source code is an unavoidable step

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks, I tried searching the whole theme directory files, but couldn't find the function or method `sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order`
so I searched for the class `WM_Nova_Restaurant` instead, & these are all the add_action() I got (using netbeans):  https://www.screencast.com/t/e4d3rmtX4Ki I guess this is hopeless, & I need to ask the plugin developer.  Many thanks guys...

Comment: Did you search the Plugins directory too? What's the context of that line that was found? It looks like you need to acquire the instance of that object in order to remove it, but there's not enough information, it isn't clear where that line is, or which plugin or theme is responsible?

Comment: Nice tip -  I did find `sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` - found in plugins - 1 file with these:   

https://www.screencast.com/t/f62DDaXa - class 
https://www.screencast.com/t/jk2zOKLZ - add_action
https://www.screencast.com/t/qclui6XvUna8 - class method
 
added `remove_action('parse_query',array("Nova_Restaurant", "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 10);`
but didn't worked.

Comment: Thanks, there's still no information about how the object is created, which is hyper critical information, and there's no information about where this code is, all we know is it's somewhere in `plugins/???????/nova.php` making it impossible to search for on Google to find the original code. You need to put `array( $????, 'sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order' )`, but there isn't enough information in your question to figure out how to get that object of type `Nova_Restuarant`

Comment: argh, you never mentioned this was a Jetpack custom post type, that's super critical information witheld. I had to dig for a while on GitHub to find the class `Nova_Restaurant ` referenced in the Jetpack git repo at https://github.com/Automattic/jetpack/blob/aa233aa9683cb4f923688a02898939dd7fc3a858/modules/custom-post-types/nova.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ Nova_Restaurant::init(), 'sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order' ]
```

You want something of type `callable`, that matches what was given when `add_action`.

There are only a handful of valid callables:

- `[ 'my_function_name' ]` aka `my_function_name();`
- `[ 'my_class_name', 'my_static_function' ]` aka `my_class_name::my_stati_function()`
- `[ $object, 'the_objects_function' ]` aka `$object->the_objects_function`
- `[ function() {} ]` an anonymous function or closure

So some translation:

- `remove_action('parse_query','WM_Nova_Restaurant', 10);`

  - Remove the function named `WM_Nova_Restaurant` from the `parse_query` hook
- `remove_action('parse_query', 'WM_Nova_Restaurant>sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order', 10);`

  - Remove the function named `WM_Nova_Restaurant>sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` from the `parse_query` hook. Note such a function name is not possible.
- `remove_action('parse_query',array("WM_Nova_Restaurant", "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 10);`

  - Remove the static method `sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` in the `WM_Nova_Restaurant` class from the hook
- `remove_action('parse_query', array("WM_Nova_Restaurant", "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 1);`

  - Remove the static method `sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` in the `WM_Nova_Restaurant` class from the hook, that has priority 1
- `remove_action('parse_query',array($WM_Nova_Restaurant, "sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order"), 10);`

  - Remove the method `sort_menu_item_queries_by_menu_order` in the object  `$WM_Nova_Restaurant` from the hook. Note that this object is empty so it is also invalid.

In future:

- Search for the place it was added
- Read the WP and PHP docs instead of guessing and flailing around
- See that it's added inside an object and try to figure out how to get a hold of that object by looking at how it's created
- See that the object is created by calling `Nova_Restaurant::init()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, effort & esp. your patience.  A hero to the WP Community. Cheers!